# Chrome update breaks site. Maybe Salvattore?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-chrome, while-loop

the latest Chrome update breaks this site: katie-scott.com. It works properly in Safari and Firefox but none of the content loads in Chrome 33.0.1750.117 (I think it last worked in version 31). I have no idea why this has broken.

It uses a wordpress loop to place all the thumbnails and Salvattore to arrange them into columns. It looks like either the wordpress loop isn't working or salvattore isn't working. Probably the Wordpress loop. But why would a Chrome update break Wordpress!? It was working perfectly!

Thanks!

Comment: I have two errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: conditionizr is not defined (index):23` and also: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null (ks-body.js):1`

Comment: It seems to be Salvattore breaking something. When I remove the Salvattore js code, the images load.

Comment: Line 335 in the Salvattore code does it:
`columnClasses = matchResult[1];`

Gives this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null ks-body.js:335

Comment: Think I've got it. Found this on GitHub: https://github.com/rnmp/salvattore/pull/41

Seems using display: none doesn't work anymore in the new Chrome so you have to use visibility: hidden